# Creating 9-Patch Images on Device

Tags: android, image, bitmap, nine-patch, aapt

I am trying to create 9-patch images using bitmaps on the device. I am aware of the draw9patch tool and I know how to use it however the images in question are customized by the user thus using the tool and adding images as resources is out of the question.

My research has led me to this discussion:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/4fb0243754ce32/8c9663d62ed7be91?q=NinePatchDrawable+constructor#8c9663d62ed7be91

An Android Engineer indicated the following: "The byte[] is the raw data of the PNG 9-patch extension chunk that we defined for android, which aapt generates; you'll have to build that all yourself, and look at the ResourceTypes.h header file for a description of its contents".

Also, according to this disscusion: https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/22f402ccedba9533
9-patch images can be 'created' using any photo editing software but the aapt embeds additional information into the image during apk compilation. It is the work of the aapt it looks like I am trying to replicate.

Is anyone aware of any examples on how to accomplish such a thing or have any tips whatsoever on how to approach this? Any comments are greatly appreciated!

Matt.

Comment: check this link it has some details about the Draw 9-patch tool that allows you to easily create a NinePatch graphic http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 0):

You know Matt,

This is great question I find, because I was just wondering the other day how I could allow the user to change the scale and padding markers with an application.

Have you tried to build a drawable instance, and try to set an empty border around it and try to feed that to view background?

I'm very curious to see if it would accept it.

That is probably where I would start your work.

Comment: Are you saying to draw something with a 1px wide transparent border and apply the black dots where needed? This I tried already, the reason it does not work is because aapt embeds additional information into the image during apk compilation, as noted above.